# AWS Ubuntu Spectre - instance dying?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

About 2 weeks after Ubuntu16.04 Spectre security update, the instances in Amazon AWS - started to die.
They do not go back to life after reboot, the logs (when disk is attached to other instance) does not show the cause (or I missed it).

I did find out, that changing he instance type from **c5** to **m4** allows it to boot and work correctly (without any system change).

My guess is, that there is a bug at AWS (**c5** is a 'new' processor type). I did spot that my hostname has changed, I've seen some cloud-init 
reinitialization - but this 'may' be normal (for now, I do run from snapshot).

Going to do some other test - but until now - I'd love to hear did you have similar issue with AWS c5 instances running Ubuntu

[image]

Note that the last running c5 instance is in zone eu-west-1c

Interesting - the instance (c5.xlarge) is active for a second during boot:

```
x:~$ ping prd-pred
PING prd-pred (10.0.2.111) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.111: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=53.2 ms


^C
--- prd-pred ping statistics ---
41 packets transmitted, 1 received, 97% packet loss, time 40312ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 53.281/53.281/53.281/0.000 ms
```

Edit - it does not work with **m5.xlarge**
Was it change from xen to kvm? Or why did it break after some undefined period of time...

Edit 
my guess is that AWS is doing rolling update of they **5**-family instance-supervisors and randomly breaks the systems...

Answer (score 0):

Dissable SSSD from autostart?
seems to work

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1746806